# IMEI = NULL in Samsung Galaxy Note 3

Tags: updates, samsung, samsung-galaxy-note, samsung-galaxy-note-3, imei

I have a Galaxy Note 3 FM-N9005 which had base band version N9005ZHUDMJ9 and build number JSS15J.N9005XXUDMK2 running on jelly bean 4.3.

I searched for its latest firmware on Sam Mobile and there was KitKat 4.4.2 update available for it having build number KOT49H.N9005ZHUENF1. I downloaded this firmware and flashed it using Odin. Everything was successful and firmware was downloaded successfully.

When I restarted the mobile, the baseband and IMEI was unknown. I hadn't backed-up the EFS Folder but it is mounted in CWM Recovery. I am unable to restore the baseband and IMEI number.
Please suggest a solution to recover IMEI

Answer (score 1):

Flash the NF2 modem, I had the exact same use with no imei / baseband http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2649176 
CP_N9005XXUFNF2.tar.md5 is the file you want